# Can anybody translate this PHP code into Rails

Tags: php, ruby, xml

i'm having a hard time translating this php code into rails.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($in);

/* Iterating through the XML and store the data points into the $list array */
$params = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "param" );
foreach( $params as $param )
{
    $names = $param->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
    $name = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $values = $param->getElementsByTagName( "value" );
    $value = $values->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $list[$name] = "'".mysql_escape_string($value)."'";
}
```

Comment: You do know that "Rails" isn't a programming language, right?

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't have much to do with rails so much as Ruby + DOM. You might take a look [here](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lapalme/ForestInsteadOfTheTrees/HTML/ch08s01.html) and in the Ruby and Rails documentation for XML parsers.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/). An untested, wild guess of the code you need goes by the lines:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(in)
doc.xpath('//param').each do |param|
  name = param.search('//name').first.content
  value = param.search('//value').first.content
  list[name] = __escape_sql(value)
end
```

Where the function `__escape_sql` is left as an exercise to the reader...